# How do I correctly manipulate the stack in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, x86-64, nasm

Q1) I have seen assembly code that uses `[rsp+4]` to access variables on the stack while others use `[rbp-4]`. I assume that they are both correct and that the only difference is which end of the stack frame is used.

Q2) When entering a function, we are supposed to `push [rsp]`, and upon leaving `pop rsp`. However, when I leave these instructions out the code runs just fine. Why are they required? Example code is given below in test.asm.

Q3) When leaving the program in main, we are to return exit code e.g. 0 `xor rdi rdi`. However, when I leave this command out it still works. Same example as below in test.asm.

Q4) Is `push 5` the same as `mov [rsp], 5`?

```
; test.asm
; Compiled as such (Linking with MSVC):
; nasm -f win64 -o test.obj test.asm
; /LINK /DEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib /DEFAULTLIB:legacy_stdio_definitions.lib /DEFAULTLIB:Kernel32.lib /SUBSYSTEM:console test.obj /OUT:test.exe
; Gives output:
; 1
; 2

bits 64
default rel

segment .data
    ifmt:    db "%d, 0xd, 0xa, 0x0

segment .text
    global main
    extern printf

PrintInt:
    sub     rsp, 40
    mov     rdx, rcx
    lea     rcx, [ifmt]
    call    printf
    add     rsp, 40
    ret

main:
    sub     rsp, 24
    mov     rcx, 1
    call    PrintInt
    mov     rcx, 2
    call    PrintInt
    add     rsp, 24
    ret
```

Comment: The answers depend on which ABI you're using, because different ABIs have different conventions on stack and register usage. From the toolchain command line, it seems you're using [Windows x64 ABI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-software-conventions?view=msvc-160). There are a lot of things you failed to do correctly. No stack unwind codes are declared (so any exceptions are going to to cause the app to be terminated immediately), the home space is not correctly established in `main`. The Windows ABI doesn't require a `push [rsp]` on entry; not sure where you got that idea.

Comment: I may do things wrong, but I get no errors, warnings, and the program outputs what I expect. I don't understand why they're required if it runs the same. How would a correct program look like?

Comment: In a low-level language like assembly or even C, it's really easy to write incorrect code that happens, by luck, to work in a particular attempt.  For instance, you may leave important data in a region of memory that some other part of the code is *allowed* to overwrite, but happens to not actually do so in the cases you have tested.  It may fail randomly in the future, with different inputs, different execution environment, or when you make apparently unrelated changes.  In assembly, "it works therefore it's right" is not a valid argument.

Comment: "I may drive on the wrong side of the road, but I get no errors, warnings, and I still reach my destination like I expect. I don't understand why that's required if I get to my destination the same either way." You have to follow the ABI because others will make assumptions that you are doing so. You may get away with it for a long time because you are driving on a rarely-used street, but you're still doing it wrong and will eventually pay the price.

Comment: You would definitely not want to *push [rsp]*; you might want to *push rsp*; but even that is odd -- at some point you would *pop rsp*, but *rsp* would have to be at the right location, so that is pretty much useless.  *push rbp; mov rbp,rsp* is a fairly conventional entry sequence, with *pop rbp* right before the return (*ret*).

Comment: You actually *are* following the Windows x64 ABI correctly in a few ways.  e.g. `sub rsp,40` reserves 32-byte shadow space and realigns the stack by 16 before calling `printf`.  Your `main` only reserves 24 bytes before a `call`, so `PrintInt` is using a custom calling convention that doesn't provide the full amount of shadow space.  If you're going to do that, you might as well go farther and not provide any.  Or better, have main provide normal shadow space, and make `PrintInt` a tailcall: `mov rdx, rcx` / `lea rcx, [ifmt]` / `jmp printf`, so it's printf that eventually returns to main.

Comment: BTW, `db "%d, 0xd, 0xa, 0x0` is missing a close quote.  I hope it's like `"%d", ...`.  Anyway, `PrintInt` doesn't depend on having any shadow space (unless you optimize it into a tailcall), so you can call it from C, as well as your main that doesn't provide full shadow space.

Comment: Hardly anyone writes stack unwind info by hand, especially not beginners, and even most production code (e.g. x264 / x265) doesn't.  Although their hand-written asm stuff is all leaf functions, not calls to anything that could do a C++ `throw`, so it's basically fine for them.  Depending on your goals for playing around with asm, you may want to understand that it's a thing (metadata associated with code addresses where RSP changes), but not worry about the details beyond that.

Comment: @PeterCordes Windows x64 ABI says that leaf functions may not move `rsp` and therefore must keep the return address at the top of the stack. Even if you don't do anything that does a C++ `throw`, there are other things that could trigger structured exceptions, like crossing into a guard page, taking an in-page error or access violation, or writing to a read-only resource (in which case the system default exception handler automatically converts to read/write, and then resumes execution).

Comment: @RaymondChen: I'm not sure how careful x264 / x265's hand-written NASM functions are about the possibility of SEH.  I was trying to describe what real projects actually do, although in hindsight that's not great justification for doing it badly.  Since they're all SIMD on pointer args, I think most of them *don't* move RSP, so as leaf functions they may be fine after all.

Comment: @RaymondChen:   Still, I wouldn't lump missing unwind info here in with using a custom calling convention for your helper functions that doesn't have as much shadow space. 
 (Or failure to understand shadow space, whichever is happening in the question.)  Beginners that are learning asm mostly for the purpose of *understanding* compiler output (e.g. to see if it's efficient, or reverse engineering) don't need to actually generate unwind info for production code.  Their toy programs to test their understanding are generally fine without.  Still worth mentioning, though, good point.

Comment: @PeterCordes I agree that if you're just getting your feet wet, you probably don't need to dive deep into the minutiae. However, what often happens is that some percentage of these developers graduate to writing production code that are still unaware of the minutiae and end up causing problems, either for themselves or for others.

Comment: @RaymondChen: right, agreed, good argument that unwind info should get mentioned in cases like this.  I might have phrased it differently, e.g. like in my earlier comments where I point out that it's fine to not do that for toy stuff, just be aware it's a thing.  But I guess you kind of have to understand the basic principle to know when you're going to start needing it, if you ever have any hand-written asm in production code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1. That is correct.

Q2. `push rsp`, `push [rsp]`, and `pop rsp` are almost **never** correct. There might be some specialized uses, but not for beginners. You are probably thinking of `push rbp` and `pop rbp`, which are required only if you are using rbp within the function.

Q3. When returning from main, set `eax` to the exit status, not `edi`. If you call the `exit` function, then pass the status as a parameter to the exit function in `ecx`. If the caller doesn't use the exit status, then you won't notice a difference if you don't set it.

Q4. `push 5` is the same as `lea rsp, [rsp-8]; mov qword [rsp], 5`.